# What titles does Littlefinger currently hold?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Just to keep it simple these are the titles I remembering him having as of the close of *A Dance with Dragons.*

- Lord of Harrenhal (given to him by Joffrey after the Battle of Blackwater for facilitating the alliance with the Tyrells)
- Lord Protector of the Vale (gained by marrying and subsequently murdering Lysa Arryn)
- Lord Baelish of {insert name of the Fingers his land is on?} (gained by family inheritance)

**Does Littlefinger hold any other titles?**

Backstory: I am wondering because it appears his endgame may eventually be the Iron Throne...

Edit: Related: [What is Petyr Baelish's endgame with Sansa?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15616/what-is-petyr-baelishs-endgame-with-sansa?rq=1)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Besides the ones you mentioned, he is also the [**Lord Paramount of the Trident**](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Lord_Paramount_of_the_Trident)

> Lord Paramount of the Trident is a title granted by the Iron Throne to the liege lord of the riverlands within the Seven Kingdoms

He receives that title in the second book, A Clash of Kings when he is made liege lord of the Riverlands (Chapter 65, Sansa VIII)

> Ιt is the wish of the King's Grace that his loyal councillor Petyr Baelish be rewarded for faithful service to crown and realm. Be it known that Lord Baelish is granted the castle of Harrenhal with all its attendant lands and incomes, there **to make his seat and rule henceforth as Lord Paramount of the Trident**. Petyr Baelish and his sons and grandsons shall hold and enjoy these honors until the end of time, and all the lords of the Trident shall do him homage as their rightful liege.
>
> <sub>Ser Kevan Lannister at court</sub>  
> <sub>Same chapter as
>   above</sub>

The name of his house is House Baelish of the Fingers (in Vale) and he is the current Lord.

Comment: Yep. Note, being Lord Paramount effectively makes him the head of the equivalent of a "great house" (replacing house Tully as lord of the riverlands). Albeit his house is not great in name or tradition.

Comment: So, he is not Warden of the East, correct? That title is still Robert Arryn's?

Answer (score 0):

Baelish self-proclaimed a title of Lord Protector of the Vale. Lords Declarant were opposed to that. Baelish bought some off, eliminated a few of them & sidelined/defanged others by revealing 'Alayne' as Sansa & supporting what they wanted (under Royce) ... an alliance with the North. Baelish took that one step further by declaring for Jon. As the now recognised (By Vale Lords) Lord Protector his declaration for (Pledge of Fealty to) Jon means that once the Vale Lords join him on the campaign to the North (i.e., no Vale Lords rebelled against him) they have accepted that fealty. Jon is now King of both territories. Baelish wanted that precedent set because he hoped that Jon would die in battle, by 'accident' or could be eliminated. He planned to marry Sansa who would have been the natural candidate to replace Jon if Jon died. With Sansa as his Queen, his lord Protectorship of the Vale, his Lord Paramountcy of the Riverlands he would be well-placed to become King of Westeros or have a child with Sansa who would fill that role leaving him as the power behind the throne.

Comment: Your answer 1 becomes quite speculative towards the end (and wrong because he's dead) and 2 is based on the canon of the TV show _Game of Thrones_. The question, however, is asking for a book only answer.