# Who is the current liegelord of the riverlands?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Premises:

- Petyr Baelish is currently the Lord Paramount of the Trident

  > It is the wish of the King's Grace that his loyal councillor Petyr Baelish be rewarded for faithful service to crown and realm. Be it known that Lord Baelish is granted the castle of Harrenhal with all its attendant lands and incomes, there to make his seat and rule henceforth as Lord Paramount of the Trident. Petyr Baelish and his sons and grandsons shall hold and enjoy these honors until the end of time, and **all the lords of the Trident shall do him homage as their rightful liege**.
  >
  > -- ACoK Sansa VIII
- After Red Wedding, Walder Frey becomes the overlord of the Riverlands

  > ... Two cadet branches of House Frey exist. **One holds the seat of Harrenhal and the Lord Paramountcy of the Riverlands the other holds the seat of Riverrun.**
  >
  > -- [Game of Thrones Wikia](http://gotrp.wikia.com/wiki/House_Frey) (To be honest, I can't find text reference for this)

Question:  Who is the current rightful liege lord of the Riverlands as recognized by the current "Baratheon" crown?

Comment: balish claim came after the frey's no? and as far as i knew the freys never had harrenhal, it was an open castle free for the taking, it was almost an insult to give it to balish

Comment: @Himarm Yes, it *seemed* like an empty gift to give it to Baelish (which is why the Lannisters were willing to do so), but from his point of view it put him into position to make the next move in his game. The Lord of Harrenhal made a more appropriate match for the Lady of the Eyrie than the Lord of Sheepshit and Coincounting, so this supposedly empty honour allowed him to claim the Vale of Arryn for his own. (Tyrion surmised as much during one of their conversations in aCoK.)

Comment: related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/120262/what-titles-does-littlefinger-currently-hold

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### Petyr Baelish.

Let's hear it straight from the lion's mouth:

> "To be sure," Lord Emmon said. "Ser Jaime, your lord father's faith in me was well placed, you shall see. I mean to be firm but fair with my new vassals. Blackwood and Bracken, Jason Mallister, Vance and Piper, they shall learn that they have a just overlord in Emmon Frey. My father as well, yes. He is the Lord of the Crossing, but *I* am the Lord of Riverrun. A son has a duty to obey his father, true, but a bannerman must obey his overlord."
>
> *Oh, gods be good.* "You are not his overlord, ser. Read your parchment. You were granted Riverun with its lands and incomes, no more. Petyr Baelish is the Lord Paramount of the Trident. Riverrun will be subject to the rule of Harrenhal."
>
> <sub>-- *A Feast for Crows*, Chapter 34 ("Jaime V")</sub>

It looks like your Wikia quote about Lord Walder Frey is typical Wikia nonsense, since I couldn't find any evidence for it in the text either.

Comment: The second link is not from GOT Wikia as in GOT the HBO TV Adaptation. it is GOTRP Wikia which is Roleplay and Fanfiction based and therefore is bound to be different from Canon sources.

Answer (score 6):

**It is Petyr Baelish**

Baelish was given the title "Lord Paramount of the Trident" by the crown, this makes him (nominally) the liege lord of the Riverlands.

Although a cadet branch of House Frey occupies Riverrun, the erstwhile seat of the Tullys, it should be noted that title of Lord Paramount does not necessarily have to come with a particular house seat or set of lands. The title is bestowed by the crown upon whom they deem fit.

Comment: See attached link on the title, which quotes AWOIAF: http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Lord_Paramount_of_the_Trident