# Didn't the Knights of the Vale half-heartedly ride to the rescue of the Stark loyalists?

Tags: game-of-thrones

If I remember correctly, the Vale forces wanted nothing to do with the conflict in Winterfell. But, because Robin Arryn was too immature to take any interest, he delegated that decision to Littlefinger.

For House Arryn, having Winterfell run by House Bolton or Stark loyalists didn't make enough of difference to go to battle?
It was Littlefinger's decision *alone* to do it (with Sansa encouragement)?
As of now, it appears Littlefinger has mostly unchecked control of the Vale army?

Comment: My impression is that they are halfhearted about their loyalty to Littlefinger, or to any other ally or associate of the Starks - but when it comes to Sansa herself, the niece of the former Lady of the Vale, or any other blood relation of their young Lord, they are truly devoted. So, they wouldn't ride for Littlefinger, but once they met with Sansa herself, they would enter the battle wholeheartedly.

Comment: @recognizer yes. I forgot about that blood relationship. I can accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Petyr Baelish is Lord Protector of the Vale.** He was able to obtain this title by marrying Lysa Arryn (nee Tully). Lysa was Lady of the Vale by her marriage to Jon Arryn. Once Jon died, Lysa assumed control because her son, Robert, was not yet of age.

At the time of Lysa's death, Robert was still not of age, so Baelish assumed the title of Lord Protector. This title grants him control over the Vale until Robert is of age.

Sansa's part comes in because she is the niece of Lysa and keeps the Tully blood alive. The Tully blood is more important in this case than the Stark blood because of Lysa.

Although regardless of Sansa or Robert, **the Knights of the Vale are sworn to obey their Lord's command.** Granted, it makes things *easier* when you give commands that have support rather than force.

Also, remember Littlefinger has been collecting titles like Pokemon...[What titles does Littlefinger currently hold?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/120262/what-titles-does-littlefinger-currently-hold)

Comment: After BoB, with no more soldiers left in the North (other than the Vale army) , Littlefinger is gonna become Warden of the North. Then his army goes to Harrenhal. Then on to the sacking of Kings Landing. But, if Sansa has a little baby Bolton... can't wait for next season!

Comment: @khyle - Now that there is the hindsight that you did not have available when you commented, we see all those houses that withheld their support in BoB becoming the core of the new Northern Army, so Jon gets to be the boss, after all.  Looks like they wrapped up all the prelude and all the important pieces are set up for a huge war next season.