# How much land does Harrenhal control?

Tags: game-of-thrones

On the *Game of Thrones* website it never says it but does anyone know **how much land Harrenhal controls?**

Comment: Could you show us your prior research please? By `Game of Thrones website` do you mean the [Official HBO Website](http://www.hbo.com/game-of-thrones)? Have you tried the [wiki](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Harrenhal)? Are you interested in information from the books?

Comment: just the lands around the castle. harrenhall uset to be the seat of the rivverland lord before the destruction of the castle. after that it passed to riverun.

Comment: @Cherubel Nopes. Lord of Harrenhal is a major Lord of the realm and is therefore expected to have smaller lordlings and landed knights swearing fealty to him instead of Riverrun directly. Also by land I believe the OP means the number of Cities, Towns, Villages that fall under jurisdiction of Lord of Harrenhal. Also it didn't use to be seat of Riverlands. It used to be seat of "Kingdom of Isles and Rivers". Capitals of ancient Kingdom of Riverlands however have changed with rule of one dynasty to another

Comment: @OP it is unlikely you will find an answer for this from the show. The info about attendant lands is almost non-existant even in the books. But if you add the books tag, it at least gives a fighting chance to someone willing to do the research

Comment: It depends on *when* you are asking about. Much like any family/empire the answer will change over time.

Answer (score 4):

<sub>Major note: This information is heavily based on the books in ASOIAF series. However, the information should translate to the show as the events surrounding Lord Baelish's appoints are the same</sub>

Based on current events Harrenhal controls all the land associated with the Riverlands. This occurs when Petyr Baelish is awarded the castle of Harrenhal to make his family seat. This was awarded to him by King Joffrey after the Battle of Blackwater for forging the alliance of Lannisters and Tyrells. In addition to being the [Lord of Harrenhal](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Lord_of_Harrenhal), he is also named [Lord Paramount of the Trident.](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Lord_Paramount_of_the_Trident) which was typically held by the Tully family and Riverrun.

> Ιt is the wish of the King's Grace that his loyal councillor Petyr Baelish be rewarded for faithful service to crown and realm. Be it known that Lord Baelish is granted **the castle of Harrenhal with all its attendant lands and incomes, there to make his seat and rule henceforth as Lord Paramount of the Trident**. Petyr Baelish and his sons and grandsons shall hold and enjoy these honors until the end of time, and **all the lords of the Trident shall do him homage as their rightful liege.** - *A Clash of Kings, Chapter 65*

---

To get an idea of the size of the area and notable towns that are a part of the Riverlands, have a look at this map. The Riverlands are those inside the black line.

[image: Riverlands]

Related: [What titles does Littlefinger currently hold?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/120262/what-titles-does-littlefinger-currently-hold)